# .NET Core warning: Do not call 'IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider' in 'ConfigureServices'

Tags: .net-core, code-analysis

just wanted to ask, last night my software was building without any issues or warnings. 
But this morning when I open the same software I got all lots of warnings in the Dependencies/Analyzers/..

Target framework: .NET Core 3.1
MVC 6

For example the first warning says

> "Do not call 'IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider' in
>   'ConfigureServices'"

I don't know what does it mean. I can see ConfigureServices in the Startup.cs but it comes with MVC template. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the template is invalid. You shouldn't use BuildServiceProvider method, because you can end up with multiple instances of the provider with different types registered within its scope.

Comment: Thank you, Kamil but I didn't use BuilServiceProvider. Maybe I used it with a template but don't know where is the code...